# Delete DHCP lease if DNS record is updated

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp

**Situation(Windows Environment):**

Three DHCP scopes with 3 different subnets.
A user uses his notebook in all three subnets in one or two day's. Now, there are 3 dhcp leases at the same moment.

**The Question is:** Is there a way, to delete the old DHCP leases, when the DNS record from the notebook is being updated?

Comment: You should look at lowering the DHCP lease time.

Answer (score 2):

To clean up the DHCP leases based on DNS record updates, you must implement any type of DNS auditing. With Active Directory-integrated DNS, this may be possible without third-party tools. Then you must get the MAC address using Powershell [Get-DhcpServerv4lease](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dhcpserver/get-dhcpserverv4lease) and delete the leases in the other areas with [Remove-DhcpServerv4Lease](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dhcpserver/remove-dhcpserverv4lease).

This way ist most likely cheaper:

If you know which devices switch between different networks, you can use a different policy and reduce the lease time for this devices. You must use the MAC address as condition.

[image]

Details: [Using DHCP policies to set different lease durations for different device types](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/teamdhcp/2012/09/22/using-dhcp-policies-to-set-different-lease-durations-for-different-device-types/)